# Dashboard authentication not functioning in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want only the authorized users to login into the dashboard, but in my code even if enter the url with /dashboard, the dashboard is accessible, but i want only the user who is admin to access it.
Below is my code:

```html
//controller
<?php

class AccountController extends BaseController{

public function login(){
   $data = Input::all();
   $rules = array(
       'email' => 'required|email',
       'password' => 'required|min:6'
        );
   $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
   if($validator->fails()){
       return Redirect::to('/login')->withInput(Input::except('password'))->withErrors($validator);
         }//end of if
      else{
       $userdata = array(
       'email'=>Input::get('email'),
       'password'=>Input::get('password')
       );
       
       if(Auth::validate($userdata)){
        if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
         return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
        }//end of inner if2
       }//end of inner if1
       else{
        Session::flash('error','Somthing went wrong');
        return Redirect::to('login');
       }//end of inner else1
        
      }//end of else
} 


public function logout(){
 Auth::logout();
 return Redirect::to('login');
}

 
}//end of the class
```

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
 return View::make('login');
});

Route::get('/login', function()
{
 return View::make('login');
});

Route::post('login','AccountController@login');

Route::get('/dashboard', function()
{
 return View::make('dashboard');
});

Route::get('logout',array('uses'=>'AccountController@logout'));
```

Please do help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Create a route group that need the user needs to be logged in to Access.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', function()
    {
        return View::make('dashboard');
    });
});
```

Before filter with Auth will restrict access only to Logged in Users.

Comment: One might consider removing  the forward slash (/) before the word 'dashboard' to avoid making it a relative route/url.